# Start a Web App When Debugging a Second Web App

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

We have two ASP.NET web apps, with one app being a test app that is meant to show a div containing a page from the other app. This functionality works fine.

The problem is that test app will not automatically start the main app when we start it via Visual Studio. We always have to start the main application and then start the test application.

Is it possible to have one web app auto-start a second web app when debugging it via Visual Studio.

Ideally, the solution would work for unit tests as well, but we can deal with that separately if need be.

Comment: Have you considered using IIS? The built-in server is not the same as a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch multiple projects when debugging.  If you right click on the Solution (in Solution Explorer), you can select the projects you want to run.

[image]